# Azure management API nodejs sdk for managing web apps

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-node-sdk

I am trying to provision a web app through Azure nodejs SDK

Are there any examples or repos that help in doing this?

1. Create a new web app.
2. set up the deployment source to bitbucket
3. sync with deployment source.
4. setup the environment variables
5. restart the app.

All of this done through management API...

Any inputs or guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the official code sample for managing your web apps [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-nodejs-manage).

This code sample includes the following:

- *create a resource group*
- *create a hosting plan*
- *create a website*
- *list websites in a resource group*
- *get details for a given website*
- *update site config for a website*

For other operations please refer to the [SDK documentation for WebApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-arm-website/webapps?view=azure-node-2.2.0).